# problem with add/remove snap-in at mmc + sql server 2005 + sql server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008, mmc

i have a window 7 and i installed sql server 2005 and sql server 2008 together on my os
when i run mmc.msc (microsoft management console) the console runs, but when i try add snap-in such as certificates, mmc crashed and give me this error:

"Microsoft Management Console has stopped working"
with two "Debug" and "Close program" button.

at the below link:

'http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winserverManagement/thread/26d0ae5f-2a15-44bf-afac-5f220d8077c5/'

say SQL Server 2008 on top of SQL Server 2005 on the same machine may cause this problem, and if you remove SQL Server 2005, problem is solved.
but i do not want remove sql server 2005, do you have any solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i succeed solving this problem.

i download and install service pack 3 for sql server 2005 from below link:

[sp3 for SQL Server 2005](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=ae7387c3-348c-4faa-8ae5-949fdfbe59c4)

and now i can add and use snap-in such as certificates in the MMC console